# Obtener error 404 Angular 4

Tags: angular

Quisiera saber como capturar el error 404 de pagina no encontrada para integrarla a mi web, hasta el momento he modificado el routing y los los paths de mi web para que cuando no encuentre la ruta de una pagina me muestre una pagina con la descripción del error 404.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

Esta solución aparentemente funciona, sin embargo quiero saber cuando el servidor me responde con un 404 para así mostrar una pagina al cliente diciendo que hubo un error 404.

Comment: Para cambiar eso, habría que modificar el servidor, no se puede hacer nada desde el cliente. Podrías mostrarnos un poco del código que tienes en el servidor.

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo en la peticion http.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `HttpInterceptor` que observe las peticiones Http de tu aplicación y ejecute ciertas acciones de acuerdo a las peticiones/respuestas de cada request.

> app.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
            next: HttpHandler
            ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (error: any) => {

            // Si sabes que el servidor hace el handling de las "error responses"
            // es decir, si el servidor devuelve los errores como instancias de HttpErrorResponse
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (error.status === 404) {
                    // realiza la acción que necesites, 
                    // en tu caso la redirección a la ruta para 404 que creaste
                }

                if (error.status === 500) {
                    // otra acción distinta, por ejemplo...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Recuerda que el servidor debe tratar las respuestas con error como instancias de `HttpErrorResponse`, lo cual es habitual, pero no está demás tenerlo en cuenta.